# Parsing Json using FasterXML for generic elements

Tags: java, json, spring, generics, jackson

I´m using java spring boot to read data via REST api.

Incoming data is specified as followed:

```
public class Element<T>
{
    public String error;
    public Boolean state;
    public T subelement;
}

public class Response<T>
{
    public Element<T> element;
}
```

Generic Type T can be any generic class such as Boolean or complex classes.

In a simple sample I tried to parse an Response element:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(value, Response<Boolean>.class);
```

Eclipse marks me the Response.class part as followed :

> Boolean cannot be resolved to a variable

I´m used to use generics on fly in order to dynamicly interact in Delphi and .NET. There has never been the urge of generating classes or pass types since you can classify T such being a class, owning an empty constructor and json wrapper takes T arguments.

Since JacksonXML requires a Class I need to find a way to solve it.

I tried a few posts here on stack overflow to obtain data on following way:

- ParameterizedType
- JacksonXMLbind Javatype

any ideas?

Edit:

Well it could be based on the List Element that it looks differently.
Here is a sample of my json:

```
{"id":1,"state":true,"element":{"response":{"data":{"client_id":"sock1591427021","protocol_version":2}}},"errormsg":"OK"}
```

this part i use to convert the json :

```
private <T extends Object> APIResponse<T> readResponse(String data) {
        try {
            var value = objectMapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<APIResponse<T>>() {
            });

            return value;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try with "result = mapper.readValue(body, new TypeReference<Response<Boolean>>(){});" This works for me.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply. I´ve tested your solution (i think i had this used before as well). For simple classes such as Boolean it works flawless.

For complex types (such multiple properties) it generated me an underlying LinkedHashmap instead of an object. So it seems not the perfect solution yet.

Comment: Interessting because I use this with complex classes as well and it worked like charm. I exchange data via HTTP-API of type "List<Set<MyCompelxDto>>".

Comment: I added the sample I´m using to the thread. Still researching..

Comment: So a small feedback from my side. @M46 your solution works under certain requirements. Your sample directly works flawlessly, but if you build a function like private <T> T readResponse(String data) and generate TypeReference within that function it seems to build a keymap. Nevermind that problem, i pass the typereference into that function and it works. Thanks for pointing out your way!